# Issue configuring nginx location

Tags: nginx

Working with nginx as my web server on a RedHat Enterprise host.

Starting to think I'm not fully understanding the use of locations in nginx.conf despite examples and what I've read.

I set this up originally just to serve our internal wiki.

I'm trying to change things however so that it can host other stuff.

Instead of having the wiki show up when going to:  http://myserver.corp.com

I want the wiki to show up when going to: http://myserver.corp.com/wiki/

/wiki is not a folder or exist on the server, it should just be a way to redirect requests for /wiki to another location on server.

I changed the following in my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    server_name myserver.corp.com;
    root /var/www/public_html/;
    index index.html index.php;
    autoindex off;

location /wiki {
    root /usr/share/mediawiki123/;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
}
```

However by adding that location info and trying to access it I see the following in the log:

> 2017/09/07 17:16:43 [error] 614#0: *1
>   "/usr/share/mediawiki123/wiki/index.html" is not found (2: No such
>   file or directory), client: 10.13.168.153, server: myserver.corp.com,
>   request: "GET /wiki/ HTTP/1.1", host: "myserver.corp.com"

It appears that it is appending /wiki into the folder structure?

Instead of it trying to access:  "/usr/share/mediawiki123/wiki/index.html"

It should just be going to:  "/usr/share/mediawiki123/index.html"

Comment: [Something like this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-wordpress-in-a-sub-directory) might work.

Answer (score 0):

You want `alias`, not `root`, in your `location` block.  There's [a subtle but important difference in how those two directives construct paths to resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647080/60003).